# Address Book iOS Import/Export

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, abaddressbook

I want to move contacts from an iPhone 3G to a new iPhone. I was wondering if it's feasible to write a little app, to rip the whole address book on the 3G onto a file or DB, then use the same app to inject the contacts on her new phone?

I know this would never be approved by Apple etc, this is not for the store, just for my personal use.

So I'm wondering about feasibility, and if anyone has any experience pulling contacts via API's in the iOS SDK?

Comment: Unless you want to write it for fun, dont re-invent the wheel. I transfered my contacts with an app. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-contacts-backup/id446784593?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4 It emails you a file that you open in your new phone and it imports the contacts

Comment: Thanks, I was half thinking it might be a little project, just for fun, (im a bit of a geek!)

Comment: Also that app won't work on her iPhone 3G, max OS is 4.2.1 ! which means i'm stuck.

Comment: Unless you really want to do this project for a learning experience, just sync the devices with iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but it's a lot of effort for something that iCloud was invented for ... lol Or use the app @RUJordan suggested.

From comments:

Use iTunes sync ? If you're really set on making an app then look at ABAdressBook Framework. It won't be a quick project or fun ! I found ABAdressBook a nightmare but I was doing some very custom stuff with it.

Comment: Can't use iCloud as the iPhone 3G is pre icloud and stuck on iOS 4! any tips on how i could develop this?

Comment: Use iTunes sync ? If you're really set on making an app then look at ABAdressBook Framework. It won't be a quick project or fun ! I found ABAdressBook a nightmare but I was doing some very custom stuff with it.

Comment: Because your answer is completely invalid. The iPhone 3G only supports up to iOS 4.2.1. iCloud support was added in iOS 5.

Comment: @CW007007, didn't down vote you! I don't think I can use iTunes with an iOS4 3G and an iOS7 4s can I? If so can I ensure my Wifes iPhone doesn't ruin my contacts that are icloud synced with my mac and devices?

Comment: Yeah you may not want to start messing around with your contacts merging. 

@rmaddy ok well I'm sorry I forgot that, doesn't exactly warrant a downvote though .. PLUS i mentioned RUJordans alternative so it's not COMPLETELY invalid...

Your simplest solution would be another 3rd party app, not sure about how many iOS 4 apps left in the store ! lol. Have a look or look at ABAddressBook.

Comment: @CW0007007 Why do you think that an answer that gives invalid advice doesn't deserve a down vote? And simply referencing someone else's comment in your answer doesn't suddenly make your answer better. Sorry, but that is how it works. Feel free to correct or delete your answer.

Comment: Life's too short. Wasn't suggesting my answer was better, merely concurring.